# Display name is empty for tensor flow lite model generated using teachable machine

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow, kaggle, teachable-machine

I am using [teachable machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) to do generate a `tensorflow-lite` model and using that model in my android app. The result from `tensor flow lite` model shows display name as empty. Below is a screenshot of my `teachable-machine` process. I have added Cats and Dogs as name though other values like index, label, score are displayed properly. Here is a sample of the output after detection

```
<Category "1" (displayName= score=0.99609375 index=1)>
```

Here is my code snippet

```
class ImageClassifierHelper(
    var threshold: Float = 0.5f,
    var numThreads: Int = 2,
    var maxResults: Int = 2,
    var currentDelegate: Int = 0,
    var currentModel: Int = 0,
    val context: Context,
    val imageClassifierListener: ClassifierListener?
) {
    private var imageClassifier: ImageClassifier? = null

    init {
        setupImageClassifier()
    }

    fun clearImageClassifier() {
        imageClassifier = null
    }

    private fun setupImageClassifier() {
        val optionsBuilder = ImageClassifier.ImageClassifierOptions.builder()
            .setScoreThreshold(threshold)
            .setMaxResults(maxResults)

        val baseOptionsBuilder = BaseOptions.builder().setNumThreads(numThreads)

        when (currentDelegate) {
            DELEGATE_CPU -> {
                // Default
            }
            DELEGATE_GPU -> {
                if (CompatibilityList().isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice) {
                    baseOptionsBuilder.useGpu()
                } else {
                    imageClassifierListener?.onError("GPU is not supported on this device")
                }
            }
            DELEGATE_NNAPI -> {
                baseOptionsBuilder.useNnapi()
            }
        }

        optionsBuilder.setBaseOptions(baseOptionsBuilder.build())

        val modelName =
            when (currentModel) {
                MODEL_MOBILENETV1 -> "model.tflite"
                MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV0 -> "model.tflite"
                MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV1 -> "model.tflite"
                MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV2 -> "model.tflite"
                else -> "model.tflite"
            }

        try {
            imageClassifier =
                ImageClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(context, modelName, optionsBuilder.build())
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            imageClassifierListener?.onError(
                "Image classifier failed to initialize. See error logs for details"
            )
            Log.e(TAG, "TFLite failed to load model with error: " + e.message)
        }
    }

    fun classify(image: Bitmap, rotation: Int) {
        if (imageClassifier == null) {
            setupImageClassifier()
        }

        // Inference time is the difference between the system time at the start and finish of the
        // process
        var inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

        // Create preprocessor for the image.
        // See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/
        //            lite_support#imageprocessor_architecture
        val imageProcessor =
            ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .build()

        // Preprocess the image and convert it into a TensorImage for classification.
        val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage.fromBitmap(image))

        val imageProcessingOptions = ImageProcessingOptions.builder()
            .setOrientation(getOrientationFromRotation(rotation))
            .build()

        val results = imageClassifier?.classify(tensorImage, imageProcessingOptions)
        inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - inferenceTime
        imageClassifierListener?.onResults(
            results,
            inferenceTime
        )
    }

    // Receive the device rotation (Surface.x values range from 0->3) and return EXIF orientation
    // http://jpegclub.org/exif_orientation.html
    private fun getOrientationFromRotation(rotation: Int) : ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation {
        return when (rotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_270 ->
                ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            Surface.ROTATION_180 ->
                ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            Surface.ROTATION_90 ->
                ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.TOP_LEFT
            else ->
                ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_TOP
        }
    }

    interface ClassifierListener {
        fun onError(error: String)
        fun onResults(
            results: List<Classifications>?,
            inferenceTime: Long
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val DELEGATE_CPU = 0
        const val DELEGATE_GPU = 1
        const val DELEGATE_NNAPI = 2
        const val MODEL_MOBILENETV1 = 0
        const val MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV0 = 1
        const val MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV1 = 2
        const val MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV2 = 3

        private const val TAG = "ImageClassifierHelper"
    }
}
```

I don't think issue is with my android app code but with the model generated from teachable machine.

[image]

Comment: You should map the display name with the category assigned. Category "1" and category '0' is what the network will return.

Comment: @V.M Thanks. Please post your comment as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model only outputs as numbers, each of the unique number representing a category.

In the above example, you need to create a map that assigns a Category to display name: `{'0': 'Cat', '1': 'dog'}`.