Unable to create a map for tflite model
I am trying to make a sign language translation app. A very similar question has been asked before, but I was unable to make a map of display name with the category assigned. I am getting numbers such as '0' or '1' instead of a 'Hello' or 'Goodbye'. I used a teachable machine tensorflow-lite model for my sign language model. Thank you for your time.
class ImageClassifierHelper(

    var threshold: Float = 0.5f,
    var numThreads: Int = 2,
    var maxResults: Int = 3,
    var currentDelegate: Int = 0,
    var currentModel: Int = 0,
    val context: Context,
    val imageClassifierListener: ClassifierListener?
) {
    private var imageClassifier: ImageClassifier? = null

    init {
        setupImageClassifier()
    }

    fun clearImageClassifier() {
        imageClassifier = null
    }

    private fun setupImageClassifier() {
        val optionsBuilder = ImageClassifier.ImageClassifierOptions.builder()
            .setScoreThreshold(threshold)
            .setMaxResults(maxResults)

        val baseOptionsBuilder = BaseOptions.builder().setNumThreads(numThreads)

        when (currentDelegate) {
            DELEGATE_CPU -> {
                // Default
            }
            DELEGATE_GPU -> {
                if (CompatibilityList().isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice) {
                    baseOptionsBuilder.useGpu()
                } else {
                    imageClassifierListener?.onError("GPU is not supported on this device")
                }
            }
            DELEGATE_NNAPI -> {
                baseOptionsBuilder.useNnapi()
            }
        }

        optionsBuilder.setBaseOptions(baseOptionsBuilder.build())

        val modelName =
            when (currentModel) {
                MODEL_MOBILENETV1 -> "model.tflite"
                MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV0 -> "model.tflite"
                MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV1 -> "model.tflite"
                MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV2 -> "model.tflite"
                else -> "model.tflite"
            }

        try {
            imageClassifier =
                ImageClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(context, modelName, optionsBuilder.build())
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            imageClassifierListener?.onError(
                "Image classifier failed to initialize. See error logs for details"
            )
            Log.e(TAG, "TFLite failed to load model with error: " + e.message)
        }
    }

    fun classify(image: Bitmap, rotation: Int) {
        if (imageClassifier == null) {
            setupImageClassifier()
        }

        // Inference time is the difference between the system time at the start and finish of the
        // process
        var inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

        // Create preprocessor for the image.
        // See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/
        //            lite_support#imageprocessor_architecture
        val imageProcessor =
            ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .build()

        // Preprocess the image and convert it into a TensorImage for classification.
        val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage.fromBitmap(image))

        val imageProcessingOptions = ImageProcessingOptions.builder()
            .setOrientation(getOrientationFromRotation(rotation))
            .build()

        val results = imageClassifier?.classify(tensorImage, imageProcessingOptions)
        inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - inferenceTime
        imageClassifierListener?.onResults(
            results,
            inferenceTime
        )
    }

    // Receive the device rotation (Surface.x values range from 0->3) and return EXIF orientation
    // http://jpegclub.org/exif_orientation.html
    private fun getOrientationFromRotation(rotation: Int) : ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation {
        when (rotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_270 ->
                return ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            Surface.ROTATION_180 ->
                return ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            Surface.ROTATION_90 ->
                return ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.TOP_LEFT
            else ->
                return ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_TOP
        }
    }

    interface ClassifierListener {
        fun onError(error: String)
        fun onResults(
            results: List<Classifications>?,
            inferenceTime: Long
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val DELEGATE_CPU = 0
        const val DELEGATE_GPU = 1
        const val DELEGATE_NNAPI = 2
        const val MODEL_MOBILENETV1 = 0
        const val MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV0 = 1
        const val MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV1 = 2
        const val MODEL_EFFICIENTNETV2 = 3

        private const val TAG = "ImageClassifierHelper"
    }
}

I was expecting word outputs such as 'Hello' or 'Goodbye' instead of 0's and 1's. My labels.txt file is as follows :
0 hello
1 goodbye
2 i
3 you


Please be more specific what you are talking about. You dumped the code of an entire class here. Where exactly is the problem?

I am sorry for not being clear. My issue is, I have created a simple model consisting of 4 words; hello, goodbye, i and you. Within my labels.txt file they are defined as :
0 hello
1 goodbye
2 i
3 you.
I am really sorry, I can't exactly tell where the issue is, but I was hoping to get outputs such as 'hello' or 'goodbye' instead of just the numbers. I thought this issue was because of my labels.txt file having numbers before the words, so I tried deleting the numbers and just keeping the words but that did not work. I still had the same results afterwards. I hope I could be of help.

The answer for the question I was referring to had this as an answer : "The model only outputs as numbers, each of the unique number representing a category.
In the above example, you need to create a map that assigns a Category to display name: {'0': 'Cat', '1': 'dog'}."
Here is the link to that question : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951602/display-name-is-empty-for-tensor-flow-lite-model-generated-using-teachable-machi"
I couldn't do the mapping the answer was talking about.
